# Would a canonical Q&A/Tutorial on the minimum needed in order to comply with DMCA be appropriate on this site?

Tags: discussion

I realize that it might not follow the usual rules to the letter, but on StackOverflow, some useful questions were let be (at least in the past). Here's one example: [The Definitive C++ Book Guide and List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

DMCA affects a large audience of non lawyers, and who better to help this audience, than the contributors of this site.

I was thinking along the lines of the "walkthroughs" that Microsoft has on their site for executing some programming tasks. ([Example](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/walkthrough-create-a-simple-application-with-visual-csharp-or-visual-basic?view=vs-2017))

Of course the answer would be just for general information ("IANAL" etc.).

Answer (score 2):

There might be a way to do this as a community wiki if we could break it down into manageable chunks and keep it from being legal advice (which would be the unlicensed practice of law).

Comment: I agree: Anyone who wants to take a swing at starting such a community wiki Q&A, please have at it and link to it as an answer to this question!